# copying a list into part of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a list that varies in size and I would like to copy it over a numpy array. I already have a way to do but I would like to see if there is a more elegant way.

Let's say I have the following:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.full((10,), np.nan)

# I want to copy my list into data starting at index 2
def apply_list(my_list):
    data[2:2+len(mylist)] = mylist

# Example
tmp = [1, 2, 3, 4]        # can vary from 2 to 8 elements
apply_list(tmp)
```

After this, I expect data to look like this:

```
[nan, nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

Please keep in mind that `len(mylist)` can range from 2 to 8.

I am marking unused places with NaN and data has been preallocated and should always be size=10, regardless of the size of my_list. For that reason, simply appending will not work.

I particularly don't like much doing `2:2+len(mylist)`. Is there a nicer/cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: That's the simplest way to do the job.

Comment: Is there some way of combining this with some iterator/generator? (obviously without having to iterate in plain python). I know about np.fromiter but not sure how to connect that to the assignment

Comment: Are you looking for speed or pretty code?

Comment: well.. both :). I am learning more about numpy and I came up with this problem. If I can improve style, it would be great. But clearly I dont want to have a performance hit.

Comment: You case matches the 2nd example in this pararagraph: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays, `x[2:7] = np.arange(5)`.  Assignment to a list works the same way - except that the RHS slot does not have match in size.  Array size is fixed, list size is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any numpy-function that could simplify this. However you could wrap it as function so the complexity is hidden:

```
def put(arr, subarr, startidx):
    arr[startidx:startidx+len(subarr)] = subarr
    return arr
```

or with sequential indexing (**not recommended**):

```
def put(arr, subarr, startidx):
    arr[startidx:][:len(subarr)] = subarr
    return arr
```

You could also pad your `mylist` with `NaN`s:

```
np.pad(np.array(mylist, dtype=float), 
       (2, 8-len(mylist)), 
       mode='constant', 
       constant_values=np.nan)
```

Comment: sorry to ask about the "non recommended" one.. but it looks interesting. I never thought about it.. Why do not say is not recommended?

Comment: I think padding isn't really as performant, the other ones will be faster. I meant I wouldn't recommend the second approach becauseit just avoids the `startidx+` by adding a not-so-readable double slicing operation.

Comment: `np.pad` is a complex function that does a lot of concatenates.  And at the compiled code level, `concatenate` does the same sort of allocate and assign operation that the OP is trying to avoid.